# Showing that $\frac{\bar{X}}{10}$ is an unbiased estimator for p

Tags: statistics, parameter-estimation

Let $X_{1}, X_{2}, X_{3}, X_{4}, X_{5}$ be a random sample from a binomial distribution with $n=10$ and $p$ unknown.

How do I show that $\frac{\bar{X}}{10}$ is an unbiased estimator for $p$ and then estimate $p$ based on the data: `3,4,4,5,6`?

---

**My try**

In the book I am reading the following definition is made: **An estimator $\hat{\theta}$ is an unbiased estimator for a parameter $\theta$ if and only if $E[\hat{\theta}]=\theta$**. Can I use this to  show the above?

In this case we have $E[\frac{\bar{X}}{10}] = \frac{1}{10}E[\bar{X}] = \frac{\mu}{10}$, is that equal to $p$ and if so, why? If it is then the estimated $p$ based on the data `3,4,4,5,6` becomes $\frac{\frac{3+4+4+5+6}{2}}{10} = \frac{11}{10} $.

Comment: I do not think you have the right definition for sample mean $\bar{X}$.

Comment: @Miguel Yeah, it's a silly mistake. I just noticed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unbiased does not mean, that one obtains the correct estimate for all realizations. It means that the *average* of the estimator is equal to the correct value. Practically speaking, if you were to repeat the experiment of estimating $p$ using $\bar{X}$ many times, the average of all estimates would be close to $p$. However, a single estimate can very well be far from the actual correct value.

In your case, the estimator is unbiased, since

$$ E\left[\frac{\bar{X}}{10}\right] = \frac{1}{10} E\left[\bar{X}\right] = \frac{1}{10} E\left[\frac{X_1+X_2+X_3+X_4+X_5}{5}\right] = \frac{1}{50} \sum_{i=1}^5 E[X_i]. $$
With $E[X_i] = 10p$ as the mean of the binomial distribution,

$$ E\left[\frac{\bar{X}}{10}\right] = \frac{50}{50}p = p.$$

This is a special case of a general result on mean estimators, see, e.g., https://www.statlect.com/fundamentals-of-statistics/mean-estimation